# Wordpress Custom fields tab is empty

Tags: wordpress, image

This morning my wordpress website images are not showing up. When i go to admin panel I can't see my custom fields: http://prntscr.com/70kzf4 . Also images in Media Library images look like this: http://prntscr.com/70l2ce

Please help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Phpmyadmin, to Table wp_postmeta, I found it in use like this: http://prntscr.com/70l3yq . So I simply select it and repair it and everything is back to its place. Thank you!!